# Tableau joining multiple tables

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

Hi, I have trouble understanding the structure of this table connection.
Let's suppose that all joins are inner join. Does this picture mean:
`Orders JOIN (Orders1 JOIN People) JOIN Returns`?
or
`Orders JOIN Orders1 JOIN (People JOIN Returns)`?

I don't understand
Why `Orders1` and `People` are both vertically aligned and both connected with `Orders` table.
(As my understanding, `join` operation is bilateral, not trilateral. My imagination is that the joining should be all represented horizontally, looking like a chain.)
I know SQL, it would be easier to explain if write a pseudo SQL script.

Comment: The picture you show is the relatively recent interface for tableau table management that defines broad and dynamic relationships among tables not explicit *joins* between tables. If you want specific fixed joins, Tableau can do that, but, if you use this interface, Tableau works out dynamic joins that depend on the query.

Answer (score 1):

The example you have taken is not very good to understand the joins/relationships in tableau.

A wire/line between two tables indicate the join on two tables with some id column (`one to many` OR `one to one` OR `many to many`).  You can check the relationship based on which field (read column) by clicking that relationship thread(line).  Why I termed this example not a good one because ORDERS table joining itself may have umpteen options.  You can edit that relationship in many ways.

So, in you example, ORDERS is joined with itself (ORDERS1).  (the result will depend on relationship type of course).  Simultaneously ORDERS is joined with PEOPLE table.  Since these tables have only one field in common, this relationship has resulted in creation of just one extra column in ORDERS result.  NoW PEOPLE is also connected with RETURNS where no column is common so I am not able to understand this relationship.

A watch of [this](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datasource_datamodel_whatschanged.htm) 5 minute video is recommended.

Translating this relationship will be something like..

`(ORDERS JOIN (PEOPLE JOIN RETURNS)) JOIN ORDERS1`

(**Last JOIN outside braces is on the result of braces but with field/fields from `ORDERS`**)